# wpf remove converter from button style

Tags: wpf, button, binding, styles, valueconverter

I'm using Mahapp Metro buttons in a wpf project. Some of the standard buttons have a converter defined in the contentpresenter of the original mahapp template.

f.e. squarebutton:

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
Content="{TemplateBinding Content, Converter={StaticResource ToLowerConverter}}"
HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
RecognizesAccessKey="True"
VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
OpacityMask="{x:Null}" />
```

Is there a simple way I can change the squarebutton to NOT use the ToLowerConverter without changing the whole template?

I tried changing the ContentTemplate in a style, but without success:

```
<Style x:Key="MyFlyoverButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource SquareButtonStyle}">     
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>  
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"   VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" />
            </DataTemplate>         
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter> 
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the `ContentTemplate` won't help you because that is just used by the  that you want to replace. You could use something like the following to access a `ContentPresenter`, but this only works on a *per UI element* basis from a UI collection, eg. you could use this to access the single `ContentPresenter` defined in a template from a `ListBoxItem` that has that template applied:

```
ContentPresenter contentPresenter = FindVisualChild(dependencyObject);
```

As that is no use to you, I won't bother showing the code for that method. The only other alternative you have is to define a new `ControlTemplate`. It should be a simple matter to define a new `ControlTemplate` *if you have access to the default `ControlTemplate`*.